# Call main methods from a outside module in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a GUI with the wxPython Libraries. I have some modules. The application beggins with a main function that call to a Main Controller. Like this:

```
from controller.mainController import MainController

if __name__ == '__main__':

    createGUI()

def createGUI():
    """
    Create the GUI
    """
    app = wx.App(False)
    host = MainController(app)
    app.MainLoop()

def readTerminal():
    terminal = consola.Console()
    try:
        terminal.cmdloop("Hola!")
        terminal.cmdloop("Fallo en la linea dos")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        terminal.do_quit(None)
```

I want to call `readTerminal()` function from another module. The modules are writing in different files. What can I do that?

Comment: The problem is taht I can`t import main module in other modules.

Comment: I can't understand the question.  from thisfile import readTerminal should be all you need to expose the readTerminal() function.  If you need to call createGUI() first I'd imagine you want to use multithreading or multiprocessing since you want to evaluate python code during the UI mainloop.  But, I have never used wxpython and your post is hard for me to understand.

Comment: @iñigoDeLaFuente: why can't you import the main module?

Comment: I have some module apart from this. In this module I have some methods. In the first lines of this file I import the main like this: "import main" or "from main import readTerminal". But doesn´t work. the message on the console is ----- cannot import module name main------

Comment: I think I don´t explain well.                                      -I have a class (MainController) this class takes the control of the application.                                               --One child of this class is terminalConsole, I use the terminal console to write debug commands. This class have a function to write into the console, but renember that the instance of this class is on mainController.                                     Can I access to this instance from another module???

Comment: Thanks for the edit fredtantini I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the main module and other modules need to call `readTerminal`, then that function should be put into a common module that they can both import from. I usually have a controller module or a utility module where I can keep functions like that.

Comment: Thanks Mike.I think that is the best way to do it. Regards